# logout after 30 minutes inactive XFCE4

Tags: cron, xfce, logout

I have a little problem here but before we go as specifications, I use a Debian 10 virtual server on a VMware, GUI Xfce4, and users make terminal access to it via RDP

That said, my idea is that when the user goes 30 minutes without interacting on the screen he ends the session.

Knowing this I have two options:
`Xfce4-session-logout --logout` and `pkill -u $ user`

My problem is that I can't use `display 0` with `xprintidle` to catch time in ms of inactivity because display 0 is being used by XRDP. Does anyone know another way to solve this?

Another way I found not so attributed is that every 30 min exactly he ends the session. For this I defined in my crontab a `pkill -u $ user`, but every time it closes with `pkill` when the user will return a session from a GUI it does not go up. So I went to use `xfce4-session-logout` with crontab with the command `* / 30 * * * * / bin / sh xfce4-session-logout --logout`, but it does not work.

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a script set up to monitor XScreenSaver's state and that calls `Xfce4-session-logout --logout` after 30 minutes of inactivity. Presumably, the script would need to be started at boot or login. Take a look at `man xscreensaver-command`, particularly the `-watch` option, which includes the following examples of state information and script to control sound based on the state:

*Example XScreenSaver State Info:*

```
BLANK Fri Nov  5 01:57:22 1999
RUN 34
RUN 79
RUN 16
LOCK Fri Nov  5 01:57:22 1999
RUN 76
RUN 12
UNBLANK Fri Nov  5 02:05:59 1999
```

*Example Script:*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $blanked = 0;
open (IN, "xscreensaver-command -watch |");
while (<IN>) {
    if (m/^(BLANK|LOCK)/) {
        if (!$blanked) {
            system "sound-off";
            $blanked = 1;
        }
    } elsif (m/^UNBLANK/) {
        system "sound-on";
        $blanked = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Users access it via rdp" that is you are running an xrdp on that server?

Then you can set timeouts in the **/etc/xrdp/sessman.ini**,
section **[Sessions]**:

> IdleTimeLimit=1800

30m=60x30s=1800s